# Saving .mp4 file to iCloud drive, saying need more space but drive saying 147GB available!

Tags: icloud, storage, mp4

I have Macbook Pro, Sierra, 10.12.6.  I have activated iCloud and it shows I have 147GB available.  I am trying to copy 20GB .mp4 files to the iCloud and it is telling me I am out of space???  How do I get it to download to the iCloud storage I just upgraded to???

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you use the edit button to explain: What specifically says out of space? Finder or iOS alert or http://iCloud.com or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you've just upgraded your iCloud storage you may need to restart your system for it to notice the additional storage.

Comment: I did that and it does not recognize the additional storage.  It is saying the space on my actual computer is not enough, is there something special I need to do to make it go to iCloud??  In the sidebar it says iCloud Drive and that is what I am selecting.  Very frustrating!!